# Recursively declaring variables - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

Normally I would never want to do this, but in this case I feel as though there's no alternative. I'm building a program in pyqt that has many label widgets, and alot of which are the same with the exception of a couple places on the geometry.

I would like to automate declaring them instead of having to declare them line by line which is taking up a lot of lines. It also looks pretty ugly.

Is there a way to say create ten variables like var1, var2, var3, etc. without having to declare them line by line?

Right now my code looks like-

```
self.folderheader1 = QtGui.QLabel(self.folders)
self.folderheader2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.folders)
self.folderheader3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.folders)
self.folderheader4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.folders)
...
```

Comment: You can accomplish what you want with `setattr`, but are you sure you want to?  Why not create a `dict` or `list` instead?

Comment: [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* do this with `setattr`, but **I don't recommend it**:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    setattr(self, 'folderheader%s' % i, QtGui.QLabel(self.folders))
```

Instead, might I suggest a `list`?

```
self.folderheaders = [QtGui.Qlabel(self.folders) for _ in range(1, 5)]
```

Now instead of `self.folderheaders1` you have `self.folderheaders[0]` which isn't really that different...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `setattr` works beautifully. However, I tried out your list method, and it worked much better and is much cleaner! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dict` like this

```
self.foldersdict = {}
for i in range(100):
    self.foldersdict[i] = QtGui.QLabel(self.folders)
```

You can later access them like this,

```
self.foldersdict[1]
```

Comment: Dictionary with integer key? Sound like recipe for list. self.foldersdict = [ QtGui.QLabel(self.folders) for _ in xrange(100)]